# How to reset a viewmodel in mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

How can I reset my viewmodel when the user clicks new button on the view that has the viewmodel as it's datacontext?

For example:

If I have a view NewCustomer and upon save, the data is saved to the DB and the newly created account number is displayed. But when the user clicks the New button in the screen, I want the view (viewmodel) to be reinitialized. Or if the user clicked cancel in the screen to clear all changes.

How can I achieve this? I am using Prism 5.0 and Unity as my container.

If I used IRegionMemberLifetime, I can clear the viewmodel data when I navigate away and navigate again to the view (by setting the KeepAlive as false on clicking New button before navigating away). But I want the form to be cleared without navigating. Can this be done?

Comment: What's wrong with `Customer = new Customer()`?

Comment: All my viewmodels are injected by the container. I am looking at the suggestion from Troels Larsen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a screen/workspaceViewModel, and another ViewModel wrapping your data.

So two classes: `CarScreenViewModel` and `CarViewModel`.

The `CarScreenViewModel` would have a property, say `CurrentCar`, which reflects what is currently selected in the screen. Then, when clicking the `Create` button, you simply set:

```
 CurrentCar = new CarViewModel();
```

Resetting partially loaded data will only lead to behaviour that is hard to reproduce. It is better to start with a fresh instance.

Comment: In my case per your suggestion, I will add NewCustomerViewModel and CurrentCustomer will be property in that. So when the New is clicked by the user, CurrentCustomer is set to CurrentCustomer = new Customer(). NewCustomerViewModel is initialized by the DI and I can have NewCustomerViewModel constructor initialize CurrentCustomer. Let me try this.

Comment: Why do people call entities/datamodels viewmodels? Datamodels should only contain data (INotifyPropertyChanged etc is "allowed"). A viewmodel contains the logics of the view and typically have commands, datamodels and collection of datamodels. Just picking on this as I see this error everywhere, even provided by ms. Voting up though =)

Comment: @Stian: Well, it's MVVM, not MVVMDM :) There really is no difference between `CarScreenViewModel` and `CarViewModel` in my example, any `ViewModel` has the purpose of readying data to be displayed in the View - even the ones you call `DataModel`. There is nothing wrong with having a `DataModel` implement logic as well. At least from my ViewPoint. That being said, I've seen various implementations of MVVM that include DataModels, Presenter, and in one case, even a Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your standard approach will be something like below

ViewModels

`CustomersContainerViewModel` which contains

a collection of CustomerViewModel s
and `ICommands` like

```
CreateNewCustomer
DeleteExistingCustomer
UpdateExistingCustomer
```

Your View will contain
the `CustomersContainerView` which will contain
a collection of Customer Objects in your required UI element
a button to Create new customer (which will launch a new screen which contains the newCustomer fields it can also contain cancel, which will just close the form)
a button to delete (can also be a ContextMenu)
a button to update (can also be a ContextMenu) which will launch a customer form filled with details from DB.

Hopefully this makes some sense... Let me know if you have problem with any of the above

Update - Forgot to add. NewCustomer Command will add a new Customer object to your CustomerCollection and that should open a NewCustomer form (or whatever you chose) for user to input the customer details. Cancel/Delete will just remove that record from the collection. Delete will update the DB as well in addition

Answer (score 0):

In my case

yourViewName.variableName.postValue("")